# use spring data jpa with ninja java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, ninjaframework

[ninja](http://www.ninjaframework.org) is an awesome framework but coming from a  spring background, I need to use spring data jpa with ninja.

I want to Autowire a JpaRepository and use it in ninja. Although ninja uses Guice Inject. I keep getting a No implementations found for my class.

1. **the repository**:

   ```
   public interface PortalUserRepository extends JpaRepository<PortalUser, Long> {

   PortalUser getPortalUserByUsername(String username);

   PortalUser getPortalUserByEmail(String email); 
   }
   ```
2. **the injection**

   ```
   public class SetupDaoV2 {

   @Inject
   PortalUserRepository portalUserRepository;

   public void setup() {
       try {
           List<PortalUser> portalUsers = portalUserRepository.findAll();
           if (portalUsers.size() == 0) {
               // Create a new user and save it
               PortalUser portalUser = new PortalUser("lsadjfl", "lsdlfs", "kkk lll",
                       "llskfls@gmail.com", "lsdlfss@",
                       "lsdfls@gmail.com",
                       new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), Boolean.TRUE,
                       Boolean.TRUE, GenericStatusConstant.ACTIVE, Boolean.TRUE
               );
               portalUserRepository.save(portalUser);
           }
       }catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
3. **the error**

> com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see
>   the following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for com.bw.dd.dsl.repository.PortalUserRepository was bound.

Comment: Spring Data JPA only works with Spring or CDI. If you want to use it with Google Guice, you have to do all that wiring and generation stuff yourself.

Comment: @dunni. There has to be a way to port spring data jpa into ninja, without writing the entire implementation.

Comment: Well, you can look at the CDI extension and try to port it to Google Guice. But other than that there is no easier possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally had to implement the whole thing. A shame I couldn't port the wonderful features from spring data jpa into ninja. I coulda used spring, but for office policy on the project.

If someone finds a way, pls holla.

```
public abstract class JpaRepository<E, K> {

public abstract void create(E entity);

public abstract void edit(E entity) throws Exception;

public abstract void remove(K key) throws IllegalOrphanException, NonexistentEntityException;

public abstract List<E>  findAll();

public abstract E findOne(K key);

public abstract int count();
```

}

```
public class PortalUserRepository extends JpaRepository<PortalUser, Long> {

private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public PortalUserRepository() {
}

public PortalUserRepository(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

public void create(PortalUser entity) {
    if (entity.getUserTokens() == null) {
        entity.setUserTokens(new ArrayList<UserToken>());
    }
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Collection<UserToken> attachedUserTokens = new ArrayList<UserToken>();
        for (UserToken userTokensUserTokenToAttach : entity.getUserTokens()) {
            userTokensUserTokenToAttach = em.getReference(userTokensUserTokenToAttach.getClass(), userTokensUserTokenToAttach.getId());
            attachedUserTokens.add(userTokensUserTokenToAttach);
        }
        entity.setUserTokens(attachedUserTokens);
        em.persist(entity);
        for (UserToken userTokensUserToken : entity.getUserTokens()) {
            PortalUser oldPortalUserOfUserTokensUserToken = userTokensUserToken.getPortalUser();
            userTokensUserToken.setPortalUser(entity);
            userTokensUserToken = em.merge(userTokensUserToken);
            if (oldPortalUserOfUserTokensUserToken != null) {
                oldPortalUserOfUserTokensUserToken.getUserTokens().remove(userTokensUserToken);
                oldPortalUserOfUserTokensUserToken = em.merge(oldPortalUserOfUserTokensUserToken);
            }
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public void edit(PortalUser entity) throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        PortalUser persistentPortalUser = em.find(PortalUser.class, entity.getId());
        Collection<UserToken> userTokensOld = persistentPortalUser.getUserTokens();
        Collection<UserToken> userTokensNew = entity.getUserTokens();
        List<String> illegalOrphanMessages = null;
        for (UserToken userTokensOldUserToken : userTokensOld) {
            if (!userTokensNew.contains(userTokensOldUserToken)) {
                if (illegalOrphanMessages == null) {
                    illegalOrphanMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                illegalOrphanMessages.add("You must retain UserToken " + userTokensOldUserToken + " since its entity field is not nullable.");
            }
        }
        if (illegalOrphanMessages != null) {
            throw new IllegalOrphanException(illegalOrphanMessages);
        }
        Collection<UserToken> attachedUserTokensNew = new ArrayList<UserToken>();
        for (UserToken userTokensNewUserTokenToAttach : userTokensNew) {
            userTokensNewUserTokenToAttach = em.getReference(userTokensNewUserTokenToAttach.getClass(), userTokensNewUserTokenToAttach.getId());
            attachedUserTokensNew.add(userTokensNewUserTokenToAttach);
        }
        userTokensNew = attachedUserTokensNew;
        entity.setUserTokens(userTokensNew);
        entity = em.merge(entity);
        for (UserToken userTokensNewUserToken : userTokensNew) {
            if (!userTokensOld.contains(userTokensNewUserToken)) {
                PortalUser oldPortalUserOfUserTokensNewUserToken = userTokensNewUserToken.getPortalUser();
                userTokensNewUserToken.setPortalUser(entity);
                userTokensNewUserToken = em.merge(userTokensNewUserToken);
                if (oldPortalUserOfUserTokensNewUserToken != null && !oldPortalUserOfUserTokensNewUserToken.equals(entity)) {
                    oldPortalUserOfUserTokensNewUserToken.getUserTokens().remove(userTokensNewUserToken);
                    oldPortalUserOfUserTokensNewUserToken = em.merge(oldPortalUserOfUserTokensNewUserToken);
                }
            }
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
            Long id = entity.getId();
            if (findOne(id) == null) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The entity with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
            }
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public void remove(Long key) throws IllegalOrphanException, NonexistentEntityException {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        PortalUser portalUser;
        try {
            portalUser = em.getReference(PortalUser.class, key);
            portalUser.getId();
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
            throw new NonexistentEntityException("The portalUser with id " + key + " no longer exists.", enfe);
        }
        List<String> illegalOrphanMessages = null;
        Collection<UserToken> userTokensOrphanCheck = portalUser.getUserTokens();
        for (UserToken userTokensOrphanCheckUserToken : userTokensOrphanCheck) {
            if (illegalOrphanMessages == null) {
                illegalOrphanMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            illegalOrphanMessages.add("This PortalUser (" + portalUser + ") cannot be destroyed since the UserToken " + userTokensOrphanCheckUserToken + " in its userTokens field has a non-nullable portalUser field.");
        }
        if (illegalOrphanMessages != null) {
            throw new IllegalOrphanException(illegalOrphanMessages);
        }
        em.remove(portalUser);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public List<PortalUser> findAll() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(PortalUser.class));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public PortalUser findOne(Long key) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        return em.find(PortalUser.class, key);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public int count() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        Root<PortalUser> rt = cq.from(PortalUser.class);
        cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public PortalUser findPortalUserByUsername(String username){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select s from PortalUser s where s.username = '" + username + "'");
        return (PortalUser)q.getSingleResult();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to mark `PortalUserRepository` class with `@Repository` as shown below:

```
@Repository
public interface PortalUserRepository extends JpaRepository<PortalUser, Long> {
   //your methods
}
```

Also, **ensure that you have got `@EnableJPARepositories` so that Spring container can scan for your repository interfaces** and provide the implementations for them and then inject them into your `SetupDaoV2` bean.

Comment: The OP doesn't use Spring, he uses Guice. Besides that, the `@Repository` annotation is never necessary on Spring Data repositories (if you read the Javadoc of the annotation, it should be clear).

Comment: Can you point to the text in the API you are referring to? I could n't find..I know that we can use any stereotype to make Spring container to scan

Comment: Yes, that applies to classes which are used as beans, not interfaces for Spring Data. Javadoc says "Indicates that an annotated class is a "Repository"". The interfaces are already marked by extending the Spring Data base interfaces (like CrudRepository or JpaRepository). This and `@EnableJpaRepositories` is enough.

Comment: You can also look at the samples for Spring Data (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples) and you will find not one interface which has `@Component` or `@Repository` on it.

Comment: One final thing, can you point me the Java doc which you are referring?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html Easily findable with Google.